# Load i18n message from specific bundle/messageSource using spring:message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Coming from Apache Struts, I'm looking for a way to specify from which bundle to get a message while using the spring:message tag like so:

**WebConfig.java (messageSources definition)**

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

    String[] baseNames = {
            "resources.messages.layout.LayoutResources",
            "resources.messages.layout.MenuResources",
            "resources.messages.option.AppConfigResources",
            "resources.messages.global.GlobalResources",
            "resources.messages.contact.ContactResources",
            "resources.messages.currentsession.CurrentSessionResources",
            "resources.messages.welcome.WelcomeResources",
            "resources.messages.user.UserResources",
            "resources.messages.role.RoleResources",
            "resources.messages.profile.ProfileResources"
    };

    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    messageSource.setBasenames(baseNames);

    return messageSource;
}
```

**What I am used to in Struts**

```
<bean:message bundle="userResources" key="label.firstName" />
```

**What I use right now in Spring**

```
<spring:message code="label.firstName" />
```

That works, but if for any reason in a huge application, the key gets duplicated, Spring will silently choose the first one from the basenames definition.

**To reproduce what I had in Struts, I did the following:**

**Custom JSP tag**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ tag pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ attribute name="bundle" required="false" type="java.lang.String" rtexprvalue="false" %>
<%@ attribute name="key" required="true" type="java.lang.String" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="locale" required="false" type="java.lang.String" rtexprvalue="false" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>  
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty bundle}">
        <c:set var="bundleToUse" value="resources.messages.global.GlobalResources" />
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="bundleToUse" value="resources.messages.${bundle}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty locale}">
        <c:set var="localeToUse" value="${pageContext.request.locale.language}" />
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="localeToUse" value="${locale}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<fmt:setBundle var="bundleObjectToUse" basename="${bundleToUse}" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${localeToUse}" />
<fmt:message key="${key}" bundle="${bundleObjectToUse}" />
```

**Typical usage**

**With specific bundle and locale**

```
<t:message bundle="user.UserResources" key="error.userSearch.required" locale="fr">
```

**With specific bundle and default locale**

```
<t:message bundle="option.AppConfigResources" key="label.smtpServerHostname.note">
```

**With key only, falls back to GlobalResources**

```
<t:message key="filterSearch">
```

I would really like to build something closer to Spring.

Thank you

Comment: You would have to replace and reinvent the whole message resolution structure as that doesn't do anything with a bundle to select. If the custom tag works for you then use it, drawback is that it doesn't integrate with the rest of Spring (nor would a custom solution be).

Comment: True. I am also not sure about caching. I think Spring caches messageSources.